# Java convert encoding

Tags: java, encoding, mojibake

I have a string which used to be an xml tag where mojibakes are contained:
`<Applicant_Place_Born>Ð&#156;Ð¾Ñ&#129;ÐºÐ²Ð°</Applicant_Place_Born>`

I know that exactly the same string but in correct encoding is: 
`<Applicant_Place_Born>Москва</Applicant_Place_Born>`

I know this because using Tcl utility I can convert it into proper string:

```
# The original string
set s "Ð&#156;Ð¾Ñ&#129;ÐºÐ²Ð°"
# substituting the html escapes
set t "Ð\x9cÐ¾Ñ\x81ÐºÐ²Ð°"
# decode from utf-8 into Unicode
encoding convertfrom utf-8 "Ð\x9cÐ¾Ñ\x81ÐºÐ²Ð°"
Москва
```

I tried different variations of this:

```
System.out.println(new String(original.getBytes("UTF-8"), "CP1251"));
```

but I always got other mojibakes or question marks instead of characters.

**Q: How can I do the same as Tcl does but using Java code?**

**EDIT:**

I have tried @Joop Eggen's approach:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;


public class s {
    static String s;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.setProperty("file.encoding", "CP1251");
            System.out.println("JVM encoding: " + System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
            s = "Ð&#156;Ð¾Ñ&#129;ÐºÐ²Ð°";
            System.out.println("Original text: " + s);

            s = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(s);
            byte[] b = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
            s = new String(b, "UTF-16BE");

            System.out.println("Result: " + s);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The converted string was something Chineese:

`JVM encoding: CP1251
Original text: Ð&#156;Ð¾Ñ&#129;ÐºÐ²Ð°
Result: 킜킾톁킺킲킰`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A String in java should always be correct Unicode. In your case you seem to have UTF16BE interpreted as some single-byte encoding.

A patch would be

```
String string = new StringEscapeUtils().UnescapeHTML4(s);
byte[] b = string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
string = new String(b, "UTF-16BE");
```

Now `s` should be a correct Unicode String.

```
System.out.println(s);
```

If the operating system for instance is in Cp1251 the Cyrillic text should be converted correct.

- The characters in s are actually bytes of UTF-16BE I guess
- By getting the bytes of the string in an single-byte encoding hopefully no conversion takes place
- Then make a String of the bytes as being in UTF-16BE, internally converted to Unicode (actually UTF-16BE too)

Comment: You dropped a `)` on the third line :)

Comment: @jkeuhlen thanks, my answer still is quite uncertain, as the String content is messed up. Maybe your answer helps better.

Comment: @JoopEggen I changed `string = new String(b, "UTF-16BE");` to `string = new String(b, "UTF-8");` and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close. However, `getBytes` is used to *encode* UTF-8 rather than decode. What you want is something along the lines of

```
String string = "Ð\x9cÐ¾Ñ\x81ÐºÐ²Ð°";
byte[] bytes = string.getBytes("UTF-8");
System.out.println(new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
```